# SVG stacked elements color overlap

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG element that contains two `<circle>` children with the exact same dimensions and position. The only difference between the two is their color: the first one is red and the second is green. I've noticed that, even though the green circle is above the red, you can still see a little bit of color shift at the edges of the circle. **Is there any way I can avoid this change in color?**

Here's a screenshot of how it looks like with and without the red circle beneath:

[image]

[Also here's the fiddle that I'm using to reproduce this.](http://jsfiddle.net/9rpux8y9/1/)

And these are some of the solutions that I've tried but didn't work:

- Trying out the different values for `shape-rendering` on the SVG - Setting it to `crispEdges` sort of worked, but made the edges very jagged. All other values didn't work.
- Adding a slight blur to the top element - Didn't work very well and even made the color shift more visible.
- Making the top element slightly larger - Works but it's not optimal since I'll be using this with an arc and the bottom element has to be exactly the same.

Any different ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a filter to dial down the anti-aliased fringe. This will have the same effect as a crispEdges *should*.

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <filter id="edge-removal">
            <feComponentTransfer>
                <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1" />
            </feComponentTransfer>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g filter="url(#edge-removal)">
    <circle r="250" cx="275" cy="275" stroke="#FF0000" fill="none" stroke-width="50"></circle>
    <circle r="250" cx="275" cy="275" stroke="#00FF00" fill="none" stroke-width="50"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Works great, thank you! Only issue is that you missed a `>` in your snippet :). Do you also happen to have any docs on tweaking this filter?

Comment: I wrote this for webplatform docs a few years ago: https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/svg/elements/feComponentTransfer

Comment: Here is another helpful link on `feComponentTransfer` http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/SVGOpen2010/Filters2.htm#S6 .. and for other `SVG Filters`: http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/SVGOpen2010/Filters2.htm